# How to retrieve Data in a JavaScript from a web page in c# ?

Tags: javascript, c#, dom, html-agility-pack

I have this  [web page](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8016642/?arnumber=8016642) and I want to retrieve the Authors part (affiliations + email).

As you can see below I tried to use HtmlAgilityPack to navigate in the DOM.

```
public string GetEmail()
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8016642/?arnumber=8016642");

            var Data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='full - text - section']/div/div[2]/section/div[3]/section").ToList();

            var Affiliation = "";

            foreach ( var item in Data)
            {
                Affiliation = item.InnerText;
            }
            return Affiliation;
        }
```

But then I find that the node does not exist (var Data = null) and when I checked the page source I discovered that the information I wanted was in a JavaScript.

[Image of the JavaScript from the page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEbMw.png)

How can I retrieve the data I want from it ?

Comment: Could you not get the innerText of the script tag, parse the value returned to get the JSON as a string, then deserialize it?

Comment: How can I get the innerText of the script tag ?

Comment: Was more asking if it was possible to do it that way tbh - i'd have assumed that traversing the DOM like that a script tag is still a node like any other html element so you could select it via xpath.

Comment: Oh ok, I will try to find the Xpath then